# Python - How to open an application like google given a pixel length and position on the screen

Tags: macos, applescript

So I already know that there is the `open -a <application>` in bash which you can run to open a window.
However, my main question is how to open a window or application in a specific part of the computer screen (computer is MacOS) and a specific length of x and y pixels. I think it would be cool to run a python program or bash script that automatically opens different apps on parts of my screen.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand the problem. What is the importance of the "length" or pixel position etc.? What does that have to do with "opening a window or application"? Are you trying to change the *position and size of the program when it is opened*? Are you trying to *choose an icon that already appears on the screen, in order to open the program*? Or something else entirely?

Comment: I don't think you can tell *every* application where to open its windows, see [What controls saved/default window sizes and positions in OS X?](https://superuser.com/q/393235/652023). However, you can move the window after it opened, see [Is there a way to exactly position a window?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/303908). I edited your tags to attract more users for this task.

Answer (score -1):

I think you could experiment with the PyGetWindow library of python to manipulate active windows (for manipulating size and position) and with the subprocess library to call the executable files (at least on windows that's how it works).